# Import to Excel from Access table based on two parameters

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I am trying to import data from Access to Excel based on two parameters. I have a list of tools which specify a project number (parameter 1) and a tool type (parameter 2). How can I filter out the tools that don't satisfy the user's input of these two parameters?

I saw this thread: [Import to Excel from Access table based on parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8475847/import-to-excel-from-access-table-based-on-parameters)

but it doesn't talk about multiple parameters. Here is where I am at so far:

```
    Dim cn As Object
Dim rs As Object
Dim strFile As String
Dim strCon As String
Dim strSQL As String
Dim s As String
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer

''Access database

strFile = "D:\Tool_Database\Tool_Database.mdb"

''This is the Jet 4 connection string, you can get more
''here : http://www.connectionstrings.com/excel

strCon = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & strFile & ";"

''Late binding, so no reference is needed

Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

cn.Open strCon

'Find the name of the tool that was selected
Dim SelectedTool As String, SelectedProj
Set SelectedTool = Tools_ListBox.Selected
Set SelectedProj = Project_ListBox.Selected

strSQL = "SELECT * " _
        & "FROM ToolFiles " _
        & "WHERE Tool_Name = '" & SelectedTool & "'"

rs.Open strSQL, cn, 3, 3

Worksheets("ToolList").Cells(2, 1).CopyFromRecordset rs

rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
cn.Close
Set cn = Nothing
```

Obviously the strSQL statement is where I need to get focused and insert the value into SelectedProj.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just wanted to add the SelectedProj to the SQL statement, this should be the trick (where ProjectType is the name of the field):

```
strSQL = "SELECT * " _
        & "FROM ToolFiles " _
        & "WHERE Tool_Name = '" & SelectedTool & "' " _
        & "AND ProjectType = '" & SelectedProj & "'"
```

Answer (score 0):

The selected property returns True if the item is selected which doesn't make sense in your example above.  Perhaps you are looking for something like

```
SelectedTool = Tools_listbox.Items(Tools_listbox.SelectedItem)
```

Note you also do not have a declaration for SelectedTool which is naughty but I guess it should be a string in which case you should not use the Set.